# Java: Can't fix FileNotFound Exception?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is the directory:

C:\Users\Tim\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Exercises\build\classes\exercises\averageList.txt

No matter what I try, the project can't find the file. I'm confused. Here is my code:

```
public class Exercises {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File aFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Tim\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Exercises\\build\\classes\\exercises\\averageList.txt");
        changeFile(aFile);

    }

    static void changeFile(File inFile) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("averageList.txt"));
        int sum = 0;
        int b = 0;
        while(scan.hasNextInt()){
            b++;
            if(scan.nextInt()!= -1){
                int n = scan.nextInt();
                sum += n;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println((sum/b));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your changeFile code ignores the file path inFile you pass in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the file with your desired path to the method changeFile() but you never use it. Instead you create a new file `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("averageList.txt"))` which is being used and can not be found. Try using `Scanner scan = new Scanner(inFile)` instead.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, feel free to mark it as accepted.